# Pass variable to all views created in a Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm organizing my website in sections, which should be visible at first glance on my navigation bar (with an `active` class on the appropriate link). At the moment, I'm checking for each link in the navbar if the current URL matches the one for the link, but it's only working for 1 URL in each case. It should be like this :

- `article` ----------------> `article` section
- `article/create` -----> `article` section
- `article/edit` --------> `article` section
- `forum` -------------------> `forum` section
- `forum/post/12345` -> `forum` section

Since all my "sections" use controllers, I was thinking maybe I could implement a way (maybe using the constructor) to pass a variable (`section`) to all the views returned by a controller, so that my layout can have access to it and set the `active` class on the proper link.

But I don't want to have to do `return View::make('myView')->with('section', $this->section);` everytime

Anyone knows how to achieve that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Request::segment(1)` to compare it with section.

If your url is `article/create` and you use `Request::segment(1)` it will return you `article` and not `article/create`

And in fact, you don't have to pass anything to Blade in this case, because it should be visible:

```
@if (Request::segment(1) == 'article')
  class="active"
@endif
```

Comment: Oooh it's a good idea. I never thought to do it directly in the view, but since I'm using route grouping for everything it should work fine ! Thanks for the tip

Comment: This is better than the Request::is('blah*); method listed everywhere else thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could also share it between all views, this way its easier to change the segment later if that changes and saves you from having to edit Request::segment(1) in all your views (if you have more)

Use:
`View::share('section', Request::segment(1));`

Then in every view get the value with: `$section`

Comment: Thanks, but my navigation is a partial view directly inserted in the layout